# How can I patch a Composer dependency to make the dependency compatible with other dependency versions?

Tags: composer, 10

I'm trying to update my site from D9 to D10, I've had quite a lot of modules to go through, and for the most part a lot of them have releases which are stable for D10, but roughly 4-5 of them only have the auto-generated patch (which I've referenced in the composer.json file)

Except for some reason composer doesn't seem to acknowledge the local patched version when I'm trying to update Drupal Core

if I run `composer update -W` I get errors like this

```
- drupal/pdf[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require drupal/core ^8 || ^9 -> found drupal/core[8.0.0-beta6, ..., 8.9.x-dev, 9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.5.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10).
```

So then I ran `composer show drupal/pdf` to get

```
name     : drupal/pdf
descrip. : Display PDF file in Drupal without external readers and plugins.
keywords : 
versions : * 1.1.0
type     : drupal-module
license  : GNU General Public License v2.0 or later (GPL-2.0-or-later) (OSI approved) https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-2.0-or-later.html#licenseText
homepage : https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf
source   : [git] https://git.drupalcode.org/project/pdf.git 8.x-1.1
dist     : [zip] https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/pdf-8.x-1.1.zip 8.x-1.1
path     : /var/www/html/docroot/modules/contrib/pdf
names    : drupal/pdf

support
source : https://git.drupalcode.org/project/pdf

requires
drupal/core ^8 || ^9
```

Obviously I can see the bottom line appears to be what it's failing from, but I have already installed the patch locally via composer which fixes this, and I can even see that my locally installed file says

`core_version_requirement: ^9.3 || ^10`

Is there anything I have to do other than reference the patch file for the D10 upgrade for these custom modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`composer update` is run before patches are applied, which is why your patch is not working, as it is not seeing the patched version yet, and therefore finds incompatibilities.

See this link for information on how to deal with this issue: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-drupals-lenient-composer-endpoint

Comment: Perfect, that's great, thank you!